I ('ll)/ ('m going to ) tell him what I think of him

(1) I 'll really tell him what I think of him.
=> I think this sentence implies a decision.
(2) I 'm really going to tell him what I think of him.
=> I think this sentence implies an intension.
I think that both are good to use, and there is just a small difference in the emphasis as I wrote above. Am I right?

Maybe the answer is: “Yes, regrading to the content.”

This question is similar to: In-depth explanation of the difference between "will" and "going to"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The first sentence can be modified to make it sound better


"I’ll tell him what I really think of him."


"I’ll definitely tell him what I think of him."



@JamesMathai so, to you, both ’ll and going to is good to use in this example to express my intention?

@LE123 I didn't mean that. To me the sentence "I will really tell him" sounds awkward. Maybe grammatically it is correct.

This question is similar to: "Will" vs "going to" vs present continuous. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm really going to tell him implies intention, as your  book says.
I'll really tell him is more like a prediction. "When I see John tonight, I'll really tell him what I think of him." But the first one is much more likely in this context.

So, I should not use "will" ('ll) to express my intention. Is using  "will" ('ll) to express my intention not good ?

"When I see John tonight, I'll really tell him what I think of him." => I don’t think this is a prediction. T

I did not say that you shouldn't use 'will' to express intention, I said that "I'm really going to" is more idiomatic in this context. In fact, I was taught at school some 60 years ago that "I will" expresses intention and "I shall" is a prediction (Church of England marriage vows used to be "I will") - but that distinction seems to be largely forgotten.

So, when talking about intention, I can use both Will and be going to, but the version with be going to sound more better. Right? But using “will” is not wrong here?

I've already told you that 'will' is not wrong here! Also that "I'm really going to" is more idiomatic in this context (determination, almost a threat). (Better is a comparative, so it doesn't need more.) As the answers to the other question indicate, it's impossible to give a definite rule for when to use each one.
